# Where to get bounding boxes of places / POIs?

Tags: coordinates, api, extents, point-of-interest

How and where to get bounding boxes of places / POIs? Preferably, for free.
For example, on OSM I can see a place drawing displayed on a may and with zooming-out one can see corners as latitude and longitude.

They are needed to test a coordinate against the bounding box in a query.

Comment: Do you mean actual points as your POIs, or a set of points?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the polygons of the places you want to analyse (e.g. exported from OSM) you can create the bounding boxes of the polygons by using the function *Polygon from Layer Extent* in QGIS. You can find it under *Vector - Research Tools*. Make sure to check the option *Calculate extent for each feature separately*.

For a single point of interest it is not possible to create a "traditional" bounding box, since a point does not have a spatial extent.

Comment: I do not have polygons of the places to analyze, I am trying to grab them. Where it's in form of boundig box or polygon, I need to extract a spacial representation of places.

Comment: If you want to get the places from OSM, you can look up e.g. at the [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) if there is a specific tag for the place(s) you like to analyse. Then you can export them e.g. with the overpass-turbo api. There's a link directly to overpass-turbo at every wiki page for a tag.